# Как найти ошибку в сложном модуле?

Tags: java, swing, отладка, дерево

Я пишу на Java HTML-движок. Сейчас я работаю над интеграцией парсера и рендера.

В алгоритме где-то есть скрытая ошибка: дело в том, что когда я создаю элементы для рендера явно, отрисовка проходит успешно, но когда я создаю их из HTML нод, полученных из парсера, ничего не отрисовывается.

Странность в том, что я создаю элементы используя те же конструкторы. А главное, я написал код, берущий два объекта и сравнивающий все их поля. Так вот, для всех трёх элементов рендера, задействованных в тесте, значения полей оказались идентичными (для рабочего и нерабочего кейса).

Как такое может быть? Две древовидных структуры, поля элементов которых одинаковы, дают разный результат работы. При этом все размеры и координаты элементов тоже оказались равными (они тоже хранятся в полях, которые мой метод сравнивает).

Кода очень много, поэтому весь постить сразу не вижу смысла. Но могу дать фрагмент из главного класса, где содержатся тесты, чтобы было понятно, о чём идёт речь.

Это сам тест:

```
public static void testBuilder() {
    HTMLParser hp = new HTMLParser("test.htm");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    hp.traverseTree();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");

    Builder builder = new Builder();
    final Block root = builder.buildSubtree(null, hp.getRootNode().lastElementChild());
    System.out.println(root);
    System.out.println("----" + root.getChildren().get(0));
    System.out.println("--------" + root.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0));

    root.removeElement(1);
    visualBuilderTest(root);

    System.out.println();
        
    final Block root2 = visualBuilderSyntheticTest();


    Timer t = new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ArrayList<String> exclude = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("lm", "parentListener", "border", "document", "layouter"));

            HashMap<String, String> fields1 = getFields(root, exclude);
            HashMap<String, String> fields2 = getFields(root2, exclude);

            compareFieldsets(fields1, fields2);

        }

    });
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();

}
```

Это тот код, который должен работать, но не работает (попытка отрисовать то дерево, что получено из парсера):

```
public static void visualBuilderTest(Block root) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Render Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final WebDocument document = new WebDocument();

    document.insertSubtree(document.root, root);
    root.setId("root");

    document.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460, 240));
    document.width = 460;
    document.height = 240;

    root.setBounds(0, 0, document.width, document.height);
    root.setWidth(-1);
    root.height = document.height;
    root.viewport_height = root.height;
    root.orig_height = root.height;
    root.max_height = root.height;
    root.auto_height = false;

    document.root.getChildren().get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    document.ready = true;

    document.panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    document.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));

    panel.add(document);
    frame.add(panel);

    //panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(9, 10, 9, 10));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(document.width + 18, document.height + 18));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            document.resized();
        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

А это "синтетический тест", который работает, создавая те же элементы на лету:

```
public static Block visualBuilderSyntheticTest() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Render Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final WebDocument document = new WebDocument();

    Block root = document.root;
    root.setId("root");

    document.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460, 240));
    document.width = 460;
    document.height = 240;

    //document.ready = false;

    root.setBounds(0, 0, document.width, document.height);
    root.setWidth(-1);
    root.height = document.height;
    root.viewport_height = root.height;
    root.orig_height = root.height;
    root.max_height = root.height;
    root.auto_height = false;

    Block paragraph = new Block(document, root, -1, -1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
    paragraph.setMargins(0, 0, 12, 0);
    paragraph.addText("This is a paragraph");
    root.addElement(paragraph);

    root.getChildren().get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    document.ready = true;

    document.panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    document.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));

    panel.add(document);
    frame.add(panel);

    //panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(9, 10, 9, 10));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(document.width + 18, document.height + 18));

    frame.pack();
    //frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            document.resized();
        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);

    return root;
}
```

Код билдера, который строит по нодам элементы для рендеринга:

```
public Block buildSubtree(WebDocument document, Node node) {
    Block root = buildElement(document, node);
    for (int i = 0; i < node.children.size(); i++) {
        Block b = buildSubtree(document, node.children.get(i));
        if (b != null) {
            root.getChildren().add(b);
            b.parent = root;
        }
    }
    return root;
}

public Block buildElement(WebDocument document, Node node) {
    Block b = new Block(document);
    if (node.nodeType == ELEMENT) {
        b.type = Block.NodeTypes.ELEMENT;
        b.width = -1;
        b.height = -1;
        b.auto_width = true;
        b.auto_height = true;
    } else if (node.nodeType == TEXT) {
        b.type = Block.NodeTypes.TEXT;
        b.textContent = node.nodeValue;
        return b;
    } else if (node.nodeType == COMMENT) {
        return null;
    }
    if (BlockElements.contains(node.tagName)) {
        b.display_type = Block.Display.BLOCK;
    } else if (InlineElements.contains(node.tagName)) {
        b.display_type = Block.Display.INLINE;
    } else if (node.tagName.equals("table")) {
        b.display_type = Block.Display.TABLE;
    } else if (node.tagName.equals("tr")) {
        b.display_type = Block.Display.TABLE_ROW;
    } else if (node.tagName.equals("td")) {
        b.display_type = Block.Display.TABLE_CELL;
    }
    b.id = node.getAttribute("id");
    b.setTextColor(node.getAttribute("color"));
    b.setBackgroundColor(node.getAttribute("bgcolor"));
    if (node.tagName.equals("a")) b.href = node.getAttribute("href");
    else if (node.tagName.equals("img")) {
        b.width = -1;
        b.isImage = true;
        b.setBackgroundImage(node.getAttribute("src"));
    }
    else if (node.tagName.equals("p")) {
        b.setMargins(0, 0, 12, 0);
    }
    else if (node.tagName.equals("font")) {
        if (node.getAttribute("size") != null) {
            b.setFontSize(Integer.parseInt(node.getAttribute("size")));
        }
    }
    else if (node.tagName.equals("li")) {
        b.list_item_type = 2;
    }

    return b;
}
```

И напоследок код, сравнивающий поля двух элементов:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> getFields(Block block, List<String> exclude) {
    HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Field field : block.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(block);
            if (value != null && !exclude.contains(field.getName())) {
                //System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
                String str = value.toString();
                if (value != null && value.getClass().isArray()) {
                    if (value instanceof int[]) {
                        int[] a = (int[]) value;
                        str = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                            if (i > 0) str += ", ";
                            str += a[i];
                        }
                        str = "[" + str + "]";
                    }
                    if (value instanceof Color[]) {
                        Color[] a = (Color[]) value;
                        str = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                            if (i > 0) str += ", ";
                            Color col = (Color) a[i];
                            str = "color[" + col.getRed() + ", " + col.getGreen() + ", " + col.getBlue() + ", " + col.getAlpha() + "]";
                        }
                        str = "[" + str + "]";
                    }
                    //System.out.println(value.getClass().getComponentType());
                }
                if (value instanceof Color) {
                    Color col = (Color) value;
                    str = "color[" + col.getRed() + ", " + col.getGreen() + ", " + col.getBlue() + ", " + col.getAlpha() + "]";
                }
                if (value instanceof BufferedImage && value != null) {
                    BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) value;
                    str = "BufferedImage[" + img.getWidth() + "x" + img.getHeight() + "]";
                }
                result.put(field.getName(), str);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static void compareFieldsets(HashMap<String, String> fields1, HashMap<String, String> fields2) {
    String result = "";
    Set keys = fields1.keySet();
    Iterator it = keys.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) it.next();
        if (!fields1.get(key).equals(fields2.get(key))) {
            result += key + ": " + fields1.get(key) + " <-> " + fields2.get(key) + "\n";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result.length() > 0 ? result : "Objects are equal");
}
```

Где стоит искать ошибку? У меня совсем закончились идеи, к сожалению.

UPDATE: перечислю здесь, что я попробовал сделать на текущий момент самостоятельно.

1. Перед созданием дерева создать `WebDocument` и передавать его в билдер, чтобы сделать процесс максимально одинаковым. Не помогло.
2. В работающем синтетическом тесте использовать идентичный конструктор, задавая ширину и высоту в -1 уже после его вызова (дело в том, что по умолчанию внутри конструктора без габаритов габариты элемента выставляются в 0,0, а не в -1, -1). Не сломалось, значит тоже мимо.
3. Я подумал, что возможно, я сравниваю структуры слишком поздно (через 300 мс по таймеру), и возможно, при отрисовке в первом кейсе всё ещё что-то имеет неверные значения.

Тогда я переписал обработчики ресайза контейнера (компоновка и отрисовка вызываются при каждом изменении размера, поэтому я даже не должен вызывать их явно):

```
frame.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {}

    @Override
    public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
        boolean flag = (document.getWidth() != document.last_width || document.getHeight() != document.last_height);
        document.resized();
        if (flag) {
            ArrayList<String> exclude = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("lm", "parentListener", "border", "document", "layouter"));
            f1 = getFields(document.root, exclude);
        }
    }
});
```

`f1` и `f2` я сделал статическими полями класса, и в сравнение в коде таймера подставил уже их. В итоге по-прежнему после компоновки и отрисовки все значения равны.

Comment: Строка `root.removeElement(1);` в первом блоке кода нужна для того, чтобы удалить текстовый элемент, состоящий из единственного символа `\n`, следующего между закрывающими тегами `</p>` и `</body>`. Я предпочёл удалить этот узел из "реального" дерева, а не добавлять в "синтетический тест" (деревья должны быть одинаковыми перед сравнением).

Comment: Ширина равная -1 означает "авто", то есть занять всю доступную ширину родительского элемента за вычетом его внутренних отступов.

Comment: в `getFields` не все типы полей обрабатываются, так что какие-то различия могут быть, а ваш код их не показывает.

Comment: А вообще путь такой, начинайте с простого (минимального) html и проверяйте на нем, постепенно усложняя и добавляя новые типы элементов/атрибутов. В какой-то момент сломается - будете знать, что именно не работает. Или в обратную сторону, начните с большого и постепенно выкидывайте части html, пока не заработает. Как найдете, что именно не работает - создайте опять же маленький простой html только с тем элементом, который не работает. И для него ищите, что не так.

Comment: Так я тестирую на простейшем файле: `<body><!-- Comment -->\n<p>This is a paragraph</p>\n</body>`, где body становится корнем (document.root). И уже фейл.

Comment: Я видел полный вывод, там вроде всё справедливо. Мне нужны были эти обработки для того, чтобы исключить вывод как неравных тех строк, где всё равно, кроме ссылочных адресов (которые, естественно, не будут никогда одинаковыми).

Comment: Можно (и нужно) еще проще. Убрать коментарий, убрать <p>, убрать текст, оставить пустой body

Comment: Я понимаю, в целом не поспорить :) Но я ведь прогнал через сравнение отдельно все три узла, участвующие в эксперименте (у меня потомки доступны через `block.getChildren().get(index)` ), и там тоже как будто всё одинаково. На пустом body будет сложновато тестить. Хотя возможно, задав фоновый цвет через deprecated атрибут `bgcolor`

Comment: Там коренное отличие алгоритмов в том, что мой код, в котором генерируется дерево - он генерирует узлы сверху вниз в глубину. При этой генерации документ отсутствует в принципе, поэтому у элементов вызывается конструктор с null документом (точнее, он вызывается внутри конструктора без аргументов). Но `document` нужен внутри метода `addElement`, например, для установки ширины блока, потому что если документа нет, там везде останутся размеры в -1, и не просчитаются реальные (хотя и это не катастрофа, т.к. реальные размеры всё равно пересчитаются потом при вызове компоновщика).

Comment: И уже потом, отдельным проходом, я прохожу по всему дереву, и передобавляю элементы (сначала удаляю из списка потомков `children`, а потом добавляю заново уже через `addElement()`, где внутри используется ссылка на `document`, которая на этот раз уже не нулевая). Самое странное то, что когда я убрал это отличие, и поменял сигнатуру методов так, чтобы они принимали документ, и создал документ с заданными размерами заблаговременно - тоже ничего не изменилось. То есть проблема и не в этом.

Comment: Есть ещё момент, которого я не могу понять: Swing генерирует событие resize дважды для последнего созданного JFrame. Впрочем, я менял местами очерёдность вызовов методов, где создаются фреймы, и на результате это тоже не отразилось.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл ошибку. Всё оказалось весьма банально: в коде добавления элементов, который я написал в "адаптере", я не написал, что если у элемента нулевая ширина, то нужно проставить ему ширину родительского блока, в который я его "подселяю". В итоге элементы подставлялись с нулевой шириной, и поэтому ничего не отрисовывалось. Вторая же часть фикса заключалась в том, чтобы после создания документа (который создавался ещё до добавления в него элементов) проставить ему размеры - что я, к сожалению, забыл сделать.

И вообще, косяк с моей стороны в том, что у меня в классе документа нет нормальных сеттеров для ширины и высоты, а вместо этого я использую публичные поля. Были бы сеттеры - можно было бы просто задать размеры постфактум, и всё бы подстроилось автоматически.

Нужен рефакторинг.